# Is there any asp.net component to write instead of adding

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

So far I know we have `LiteralControl` and `PlaceHolder` that we can use to add controls to ASP.NET page dynamically at run time.

To add html code to `LiteralControl` we use

```
LiteralControl.Text = "Some HTML/Text"
```

and for `PlaceHolder` we use

```
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Some HTML/Text"))
```

I'm looking for a component that I can write to it like what I do with `Response.Write(...)` but I need it to write in a designated place in page. I need to call this many times to send small chunks of html code to output to save memory.

So the component usage will be something like this:

in aspx page I'll put:

```
<body>
...
<div>
<asp:componentName ID="SomeComp" runat="server" />
</div>
...
</body>
```

And in my code behind, I'll use this (*Imagine a big number for SetCount*):

```
for (int i;i<SetCount;i++){
  SomeComp.Write("Some Text/HTML Code");
}
While(Read.Read()){
  SomeComp.Write("Some More Text/HTML Code");
}
```

FYI Adding to strings in `DOT.NET` is very slow so `LiteralControl` is not a good choice.

Creating an StringBuilder and using

```
LiteralControl.Text = StringBuilder.ToString()
```

is not an option because it keeps all string in memory until you assign it to control and dispose it.

```
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Some HTML/Text"))
```

is not an option because it creates one LiteralControl for each chunk of html I add to it and again it uses lots of memory that for me is limited.

My Intranet Website has about 500 Calls for same page in a second and it generates a huge spike in memory use that makes IIS stop responding to requests for other applications.

Comment: Perhaps using a `div` with jQuery would help?

Comment: So you want the behavior of LiteralControl but something faster?  Since its Render call is just output.Write(this._text), I'm not sure how you'll get faster and still be a (well-behaving) control.  Perhaps <%= foo %> would be a better fit for you?

Comment: @JamesManning, Thanks for your Idea, `LiteralControl` is fast but its input is string and Adding to that output is string `+`. I'm sure you know `DOT.NET` is very slow handling strings. The Case that I'm looking is LiteralControl.Append('Some HTML/Text') that writes directly to designated area in page.

Comment: @BobSort - It is simply not true that .net handles string concatenation slowly. As with any language, it depends greatly on what and how you are doing your concatenation. IMO, the best solution would be to add memory (and perhaps processors) and look into output caching.

Comment: @Thomas, You are not completely correct, look at following links for a few benchmark samples http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-write First link compares the output of the `StringBuilder` and `String` and second link compares different method of writing to HTTP Buffer

Comment: @Thomas; Concatenation of strings are always slower than StringBuilders except rare cases, because it creates another memory space that can fit concatenation of strings, then copies both strings to new place and then free's the memory for old string. `StringBuilder` on the other hand, only keeps the address for each chunk of string in memory and when `ToString()` method is used it reads each memory location and concatenate them all at once. no freeing memory will happen until `StringBuilder` is disposed

Comment: @Thomas; Output caching is a good idea but adding memory is not possible because I'm already at max memory that my Server supports.

For now I guess I'll stick to @Bsarmady;'s solution and create a component for my problem

Comment: @BobSort - *except in rare cases* such as say a scenario where there is a single concatenation? I'm fully aware of how StringBuilder works and I'm also aware there is a threshold after which SB is more efficient than standard concats. That also means the reverse is true. I stand by my statement: it depends greatly on what and how you are concatenating. The blanket statement that concatenation in .net is slow is simply false.

Comment: @BobSort - *I'm already at max memory that my Server supports*. Time for a new server and/or a new approach. If you can max out say 128 GB-256 GB of RAM, then there is a good chance something is amiss with your approach. If your server can't take that much RAM, it's time to look to other places for servers and think about designing your app to scale out.

Comment: @BobSort - Btw, it should be noted that using StringBuilder is a form of concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Far I'm not aware of such internal `ASP.NET` component.

For this matter I suggest 3 solution:

- Use traditional `Response.Write(...)` and write everything with that.
  if you are using Master Page or have some other components. you can
  create a copy in memory and then write its partial output to Response
  Buffer, then Write your part of code and then Rest of page.
- Use a third party component to handle this matter
- Or Write your own component inherit it from PlaceHolder and generate your output in Render method. it directly writes your output to Response Buffer and is not using memory more than component code itself. (this is how I solved my own similar problem)

One more thing to consider is if your data is no changing a lot you can cache your page to reduce the hits on IIS too.

Answer (score 0):

for the problem of creating a single LiteralControl object for each html element, you can use Html32TextWriter to render all of your html elements first, and then use a LiteralControl to put it on the page :

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var writer = new StringWriter(sb);
    var html = new Html32TextWriter(writer);

    html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P);
    html.WriteEncodedText("paragraph1");
    html.RenderEndTag();
    ...
    ...
    html.Flush();

    var outputHtml = sb.ToString();

    placeHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(outputHtml));
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully! What I said creating one literal control for each chunk of html code that I'm adding to `PlaceHolder` is a drawback for me, meaning I don't want that!

As I explained I like to add small chunks of html code to my output that reduces the memory usage in server and also is faster than adding a big string made in memory before adding to HTTP buffer.

Comment: I didn't mean using several LiteralControl neither, as i said you can build your whole desired elements using HtmlTextWriter and at the end get corresponding html output and add it as a "single" LiteralControl.

If you mean how to use "unbuffered response" to have a smaller response buffer on the server then it's a whole different question.

Comment: You can directly use `StringBulder.ToString()`. so your solution would be easier with sb.Appent("...");placeHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));

The IIS buffer memory is not a big problem, the ASP.NET memory is the bigger problem. my ASP.NET process sometimes consumes 1.5gig of my memory and ISS only uses 200megs at same time.